# Why does this process keep showing up in my Apache server status?

Tags: apache-2.2

I keep seeing this "..reading.." process in my Apache Server Status, does anyone know what this is from?

It seems when the server performance is degrading, I see a few of these, I would love to know what they mean and how (if possible) to prevent it.

[image]

The servers (3 web servers) are running RHEL and are hosting a PHP/MySQL application.

Answer (score 1):

Something has opened a connection the server but not is not finished asking for anything yet.

By default these connections will be left open for 5min, you can tweak this by setting the timeout directive in you apache.conf see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout

Comment: Correct: the `accept` call has returned, but the server has not yet seen a full http request (or maybe not even the first full line of it.)  If the client is on a slow connection it may take a while for the request to get through, or you might see this if the connection stalls.  It's probably not a problem.